# Why is the named range's corresponding sheetId null, but the actual sheet's sheetId property is 0?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get data from a sheet based on a user specified named range.

So, to do that I get the sheet ID that the named range is currently on, and the value is null.

Now, I have to find the sheet with the same sheet ID(in this case null), so I can get its name and construct a range in A1 notation for a values.get API call.

But, what boggles me is that, when using spreadsheets.get and iterating over the sheets, the corresponding sheet's sheetId is 0, not null.

This can be easily replicated by creating a test sheet with a named range and using **Try this API** on the [spreadsheets.get API reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get).

Any specific reason for that? It only seems logical to be consistent and provide the same values.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour seems to be a bug. I have filed it, you can check it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/150672453)

Comment: Thanks, but you haven't described it correctly. The `sheetId` from the named range is missing because its value is null. The value should be 0 (as it is when getting the `sheetId` via the field `sheets.properties`).

Comment: Well, when making the request you dont get the sheetid field at all (that is why when you look for it is null or not existing). If the sheetid field would be there it would give you the actual id of the sheet the namedrange is in :D